# Nunit DynamicMock C# Presenter class

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, mocking, nunit

im new to Nunit testing and I was hoping someone could please provide me with a brief explaination or even a link to a site where I can get a nice explaination and example code for using DynamicMock.ExpectAndReturn.

Im trying out the MVP pattern, and my presenter class I have setup unit test as follows

```
mock = new DynamicMock(typeof(I_MyInterface));
View = new MyPresenterClass((I_MyInterface)mock.MockInstance);
view.Initialise();
```

I have a string property "Name", I wanted to make sure that the code below is a valid presenter test? I tried the following code

```
mock.ExpectAndReturn("get_Name", "Yoda");
Assert.AreEqual("Yoda", ((I_MyInterface)mock.MockInstance).Name);
```

My last question is, how can I test a method form my presenter correctly returned a value and set a property correctly. For example a method

```
public bool NameIt(int i)
{
     if(i<20)
     {
          view.Name="Yoda";
          return true;
     }
     return false;
 }
```

Could someone please show me how I could test this via the dynamic mocking?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ExpectAndReutrn.

```
 // Tell that mock object when the "GetPeople" method is 
 // called to return a predefined list of people
 personRepositoryMock.ExpectAndReturn("GetPeople", peopleList);
```

Full example is http://www.zorched.net/2007/03/10/mocking-net-objects-with-nunit/